# keyboard closes each time

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

I have a problem with my authentification screen, when i try to put something in my TextInput my keyboard closes.

Can someone help and tell me if there is an error in my code.
I tried to change my native-screen dependency (version 3.10.1) and it's still the same problem.

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

// Screens
import MainContainerScreen from '../MainContainer';
import RegisterScreen from './RegisterScreen';
import ForgotPasswordScreen from './ForgotPasswordScreen';

// Screen Names
const MainContainerName = "Main";
const registerName = "Inscription";
const forgotPasswordName = "Mot de passe oublié";


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function LoginPage() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const handleLogin = (navigation) => {
  // Redirection vers l'interface MainContainer (TabNavigator)
    navigation.navigate(MainContainerName);
  };
  

  const handleForgotPassword = (navigation) => {
    // Redirection vers la page de réinitialisation du mot de passe
    navigation.navigate(forgotPasswordName);
  };

  const handleFirstTimeLogin = (navigation) => {
    // Redirection vers un autre écran pour la première connexion
    navigation.navigate(registerName);
  };

  function Login({ navigation }) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={require('../../assets/icon.png')} style={styles.logo} />

        <TextInput
          placeholder="Adresse e-mail"
          value={email}
          onChangeText={setEmail}
          style={styles.input}
        />

        <TextInput
          placeholder="Mot de passe"
          value={password}
          onChangeText={setPassword}
          secureTextEntry
          style={styles.input}
        />

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleLogin(navigation)} style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Connexion</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleForgotPassword(navigation)}>
          <Text style={styles.forgotPasswordText}>Mot de passe oublié</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleFirstTimeLogin(navigation)}>
          <Text style={styles.firstTimeLoginText}>Première connexion</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
      <Stack.Screen name={forgotPasswordName} component={ForgotPasswordScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
      <Stack.Screen name={registerName} component={RegisterScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
      <Stack.Screen name={MainContainerName} component={MainContainerScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  logo: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    marginBottom: 50,
  },
  input: {
    width: '80%',
    height: 40,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginBottom: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    width: '80%',
    height: 40,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  forgotPasswordText: {
    color: 'blue',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  firstTimeLoginText: {
    color: 'blue',
  },
});
```

Comment: Could you please provide a video recording of the issue happening? That would be helpful as this can happen in a couple of different scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have created the Login component inside your Stack Component and you declared the email and password states in the Stack Component so when you change the email or password states the Stack Component is re-rendered and along with that Login component unmounted (or destroyed completely) and mounted again. That's why the keyboard disappears. So in order for your code to work you can move Login Component outside the Stack Component and move the password and email state and all the navigation handlers inside the Login Component.

The corrected code is given below.

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
} from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
// Screens
import MainContainerScreen from "./MainContainerScreen";
import RegisterScreen from "./RegisterScreen";
import ForgotPasswordScreen from "./ForgotPasswordScreen";

// Screen Names
const MainContainerName = "Main";
const registerName = "Inscription";
const forgotPasswordName = "Mot de passe oublié";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function Login({ navigation }) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handleLogin = (navigation) => {
    // Redirection vers l'interface MainContainer (TabNavigator)
    navigation.navigate(MainContainerName);
  };

  const handleForgotPassword = (navigation) => {
    // Redirection vers la page de réinitialisation du mot de passe
    navigation.navigate(forgotPasswordName);
  };

  const handleFirstTimeLogin = (navigation) => {
    // Redirection vers un autre écran pour la première connexion
    navigation.navigate(registerName);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image source={require('../../assets/icon.png')} style={styles.logo} />

      <TextInput
        placeholder="Adresse e-mail"
        value={email}
        onChangeText={setEmail}
        style={styles.input}
      />

      <TextInput
        placeholder="Mot de passe"
        value={password}
        onChangeText={setPassword}
        secureTextEntry
        style={styles.input}
      />

      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => handleLogin(navigation)}
        style={styles.button}
      >
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Connexion</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleForgotPassword(navigation)}>
        <Text style={styles.forgotPasswordText}>Mot de passe oublié</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleFirstTimeLogin(navigation)}>
        <Text style={styles.firstTimeLoginText}>Première connexion</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}


export default function LoginPage() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Login"
          component={Login}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name={forgotPasswordName}
          component={ForgotPasswordScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name={registerName}
          component={RegisterScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name={MainContainerName}
          component={MainContainerScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  logo: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    marginBottom: 50,
  },
  input: {
    width: "80%",
    height: 40,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginBottom: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    width: "80%",
    height: 40,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  forgotPasswordText: {
    color: "blue",
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  firstTimeLoginText: {
    color: "blue",
  },
});
```